# Please take the time to tailor-write comments for new users' questions

Tags: discussion, comments

I saw this today:

[image: comments on a new user's question: the first is a detailed message asking for specific kinds of details, the second is a generic Community-bot message asking for vague "additional details", and the third is a thank-you message from the original poster noting that they've added in details the first comment asked for]

The second comment there is attributed to the [Community user](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), which is a feature [from the last review queue update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369272/resolving-community-user-and-share-feedback-issues-in-review-queues). And... it's *significantly* less useful than the first one.* While it is quicker to just click a radio button to select a premade auto-comment, **providing specific, actionable feedback** is what new users need to become productive citizens of our newly graduated site.

It may be obvious to you (the experienced reviewer) what the problem is, but as a previously new user** I can tell you *we do not know* even where to look for what to do. Having someone take their time to help you figure this place out is what encourages people to stick around.

We're not such a large site that the premade comments become a necessary evil to keep you sane as you grind through an endless review queue, while countless questions stream in from inexperienced users. We need these new users to grow. If you're in a review queue, "Share feedback" as yourself and write a custom comment. Even if you're not, write a comment when it's needed and you can spare the little bit of time. Please.

* Yes, yes, the first one is from me, so I have some bias here.

** We all were, once. Ah, the memories.

Comment: "*We all were, once. Ah, the memories.*" - Indeed! The Stack Exchange turns, and Ages come and pass, leaving newbies who become users. Users rise to regulars, but even regulars should never have forgotten the Age that gave them birth.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I remember laughing out loud when I saw that in your chat profile... inspired me to have some levity with my own

Comment: When I saw that community bot answer, I was actually wondering whether I should delete it, or first talk about it in our chatroom.

Comment: @Tsundoku Thankfully we have the ability to delete Community bot comments now. When they first introduced this "feature", those comments were not deletable even by moderators.